# Javascript alerts and prompts stop appearing after extended period on a page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 m

I have a single page intranet web app which is kept open for hours on by users. Prompts and alerts (from Javascript) stop working on the page randomly, mostly after the page has been kept open and in use for extended periods.

When the browser is in this state

- Everything else works except Javacript alerts and prompts
- If i open the same page in a new tab, alerts work there
- if i run "alert('helo')" from a Javascript console, nothing shows
- if i run "prompt('helo')" from a Javascript console, nothing shows as well
- After a page refresh, alerts work again

There are no popup blockers and this does not look like a popup issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors when attempting to run alerts or prompts after they stop working?

Comment: For `alert`'s or `prompt`'s that appear multiple times on a page, Chrome includes a checkbox that says `Prevent this page from opening additional dialogs.` Is it possible this checkbox is getting checked? Open [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qzcwujm1/1/) link in chrome to see the message...

Comment: @TimeDead After getting in to this state, running alert and prompt from the console act like they are null statements. No error, but no effect whatsoever, nothing on the console either

Comment: @War10ck I checked with the users who report this issue to see if they have clicked on "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs". They don't remember doing so. Also, I just selected clicked on the link you included, but even after selecting to block more popups, alert("hello") comes up just fine.

Comment: Could it be possible that after a certain period of time chrome would automatically block pop ups especially if you're getting multiple at a time? I don't think it's a code issue since they do work and you're not getting an error. Makes me feel like it is a browser issue

Comment: I believe it is a browser issue as well. Since this issue is intermittent and takes hours to reproduce, i am not sure how to pursue this any further. Popups are essential to the apps functionality and them not showing up ends up in users not seeing critical information.

Comment: It's possible Chrome as implemented some checks to prevent users from being bombarded by alerts when coming back to a tab left in the background for hours. It would make sense. I'd suggest to refactor the code to not use JS `alert` but something more integrated with the website. There are some "drop-in" replacements and libraries for this.

Comment: @pawel the page is not left unused, it is rather heavily used throughout. It is a single AJAX driven web page with panels that are refreshed. Refactoring using custom alert windows is a rather intense effort. Especially since i am still not sure if that is the real cause.

Comment: @user2453831 so maybe the tab being in background isn't a requirement to trigger the alert superssion. Either way alerts are ugly and have this outdated feel to them, this problem could be an opportunity to allocate reosurces for investigating and fixing the user experience :)

Comment: @pawel it makes sense, but do you have evidence to suggest alerts are suppressed by Chrome on purpose?

Comment: @user2453831 no, the only "evidence" is your description of the problem. However it wouldn't suprise me if it was implemented now or in the future.